# rails 3.1 model and view and controller association with 3 tables association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, view, model, controller

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hashtag, :foreign_key => "hashtag_id"
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

Now if in the hashtag's show view we want to show all the messages belonging to hashtag and also an input box to create a new message.
Any kind of code examples or links or videos will be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

If the association is set up correctly, calling `hashtag.messages` will return an array of messages associated with that specific hashtag.

To create messages on the hashtag 'show' page you'll need to create the new message in hashtag#show.

```
@hashtag.messages.build
```

On the hashtags/show.html page, add a form for the user to edit the *message*.  Then submit the *message* to message#create.

Comment: so create a message we need both the hashtag_id and user_id, even if the user is logged in, will it be in the message hash ?

Comment: Set the message's user_id in the controller before you actually create it.
You should be able to get the user_id from your authorization system. Most use the method `current_user` to retrieve the user or their id.